# Angular js Images slider example

Tags: angularjs, css

```js
<body ng-app="myApp">
  
  <div  ng-controller="slideShowController" class="imageslide" ng-switch='slideshow' ng-animate="'animate'">
   <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
    <img src="../images/ship.png" />
   </div> 
   <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="2">
     <img src="../images/cargo.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
    <img src="../images/lake.png" />
   </div> 
   <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="4">
    <img src="../images/cargo2.png" />
   </div> 
  </div>  
  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular-responsive']);
  app.controller('slideShowController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  //function slideShowController($scope, $timeout) {   
    var slidesInSlideshow = 4;
   var slidesTimeIntervalInMs = 3000; 
    
    $scope.slideshow = 1;
    var slideTimer =
      $timeout(function interval() {
        $scope.slideshow = ($scope.slideshow % slidesInSlideshow) + 1;
        slideTimer = $timeout(interval, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
      }, slidesTimeIntervalInMs); 
  });
  </script>
  
 </body>
```

```html
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="../bower_components/angular-responsive/src/responsive-directive.js"></script>
         <script src="../bower_components/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/style2.css" />
    
    <link href="../bower_components/style3.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I need Images slider plugin in angular js. It must work both desktop and mobile. Can you please send one example for Image slider Angular JS.

This is the code I am using. Here I slide function is working. But no responsive. For mobile view it is working.

Comment: Have you tried anything.. please show your work here

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [this](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) library.
It's an Angular carousel, which is swipable (for mobile) but can also be used with regular navigation for desktop.

Comment: After clicking left or right arrow only Image is sliding. I want auto slide. Auomatically it should slide.

Comment: Yeah, there is an option. Add rn-carousel-auto-slide="10" to make it auto-slide after 10 sec. Read up on the documentation before making a comment like this please :-)

Comment: It is allready lazy enough for you to ask this on stackoverflow instead of googling for some sliders yourself, so atleast take the effort to look through the provided sliders' documentation..

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this: https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider

But please keep in mind you should try something yourself, post your code and then you will (probably) receive an answer. Don't ask for the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this : http://jsfiddle.net/4m8pppyy

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> <div class="company-slide-outer"><company-project-directive></company-project-directive></div>
```

Comment: Try to add some explanations to your examples.